# What does "mappings" do in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I just started learning Elasticsearch. I am trying out to create index, adding data, deleting data, and search data.
I can also understand the settings of Elasticsearch.

**When using "PUT" to use settings**

```
{
"settings": {
"index.number_of_shards" : 1,
"index.number_of_replicas" : 0
 }
}
```

**When using "GET" to retrieve settings information**

```
{
"dsm" : {
"settings" : {
  "index" : {
    "creation_date" : "1555487684262",
    "number_of_shards" : "1",
    "number_of_replicas" : "0",
    "uuid" : "qsSr69OdTuugP2DUwrMh4g",
    "version" : {
      "created" : "7000099"
    },
    "provided_name" : "dsm"
  }
}
}
}
```

However,

> What does "mappings" do in Elasticsearch?

```
{
  "kibana_sample_data_flights" : {
"aliases" : { },
"mappings" : {
  "properties" : {
    "AvgTicketPrice" : {
      "type" : "float"
    },
    "Cancelled" : {
      "type" : "boolean"
    },
    "Carrier" : {
      "type" : "keyword"
    },
    "Dest" : {
      "type" : "keyword"
    },
    "DestAirportID" : {
      "type" : "keyword"
    },
    "DestCityName" : {

    },  // just part of data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mapping document is a way of describing the structure of your data and defining the types eg boolean, text, keyword. These types are important as they determine how your fields are indexed and analysed.

Elasticsearch supports dynamic mapping, so effectively performs an automatic best guess of the appropriate types but you may wish to override these.

I found this to be a useful article to explain the mapping process:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-mapping-introduction

Indexing is determined by the field type for example where the type is 'keyword' the search engine will be expecting an exact match, when the type is 'text' the search engine will be trying to determine how well the document matches the query term and in so doing so will be performing a 'full text search'.

So for example:
- A search for jump should also match jumped, jumps, jumping, and perhaps even leap.

This is a great article describing exact vs full text search and is where I took the jump example: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_exact_values_versus_full_text.html

Much of the power of elasticsearch is in the mapping and analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Its the mapping of the index. This means it describes the data that is stored in this index. Take a deeper look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html).